# Data returning null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a chat application where I have implemented push notifications.

**Problem**
When I click on a notification, it should send me to a specific acitivty. This works when the app is in the foreground, but the app crashes when the application is in the background or killed. It does so because data I'm sending from my cloud function is null on the client side. Can anybody see why it is returning null?

**What I have done**

Cloud function:

```
const pushId = context.params.pushId;

const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: originalText.message,
        body: originalText.name,
        click_action: "TEST"
    },
    data: {
        uid: pushId,
    }
};
```

Android Client:

```
    String notificationTitle = "";
    String notificationBody = "";
    String click_action = "";

    notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

    String pushId = remoteMessage.getData().get("uid");

    Intent intent = new Intent(click_action);
    intent.putExtra("pushId", pushId);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: have you tried to get uid inside your Client, as pushId only seems to be the value of uid

Comment: That was a mistake in the post, now edited. I have tried to get the "uid" key, but it returns null when the app is in background, but works perfectly in foreground